# Using regular expression in CSS to match numbers

Tags: css, regex

I have bunch of rows have a ID contains a number as a name like this:

```
<tr id="839" class="stock">
...
<tr id="2493" class="stock">
...
<tr id="4156" class="stock">
...
```

My CSS rule fails when I apply this:

```
tr[id=^['[0-9]'] {
//CSS rules goes here
}
```

Comment: Which elements exactly you want to target?

Comment: Those classes don't contain numbers..

Comment: Also, related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903313/using-regular-expression-in-css

Comment: @enigma I corrected the question, thank you for this notice.

Comment: @sdcr All rows that have ID name as number.

Comment: You are messing up ids with class, and also your selector is totally invalid. There are no regex CSS selectors, only a limited support is available for example to match a concrete prefix.

Comment: @CMate I corrected again, It looks like the answer is "only a limited support is available for example to match a concrete prefix.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example you'd be better off targeting them as

```
tr.stock {}
```

Note: [IDs shouldn't start with a number](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)

JQuery could also be an option: [jQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions/190255#190255)

Comment: Unfortunately not all rows will have the same class name.

Comment: If you're in charge of the data generation, either ensure they all have predicable classes (different classes is fine, so long as you know what they are), or that the ids have a predictable starting string.  Or you could use JQuery as I've mentioned in my answer.