# Regex in CSS sheet

Tags: regex, css-selectors

I need to style any element that has the class or ID that has the following pattern:

hide_this + any_string_of_number

example:
hide_this364526452
hide_this0090890

Any tip? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`hide_this\d+`

This regex will match `hide_this` and then between one and unlimited digits.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vpvEso/1)

Comment: Thanks Nick. But how would this implementable in CSS? I have many elements with this class or ID. hide_this364526452

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8903313/7431860), it describes how to use regex-esque content in a css selector.