# CSS selector for repeatable table fields

Tags: css

I have a table that is repeatable (made with php and javascript). The fields ID is "this_is_field_0"and name is "this_is_field[0]". The next field ID becomes "this_is_field_1" and so on. They increment by 1 for each time I add a new table group.

Is it possible to select all of these fields with CSS? Something like "#this_is_field[*]"?

Comment: Look on this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903313/using-regular-expression-in-css

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an attribute selector

```
[id^="this_is_field_"]
```

This will select all the fields where the `id` starts with `this_is_field_` and as a side effect it will keep the specificity low.

Answer (score 0):

The Operator ^ - Match elements that starts with

```
td[id^="this_is_field_"] { /* */}
```

The Operator $ - Match elements that ends with

```
td[id$="field_2"] { /* */}
```

The Operator * - Match elements that have an attribute containing

```
td[id*="is_field"] { /* */}
```