# Is there a way to use variable CSS selector which can selectively apply css to html element which has classes which is a variable?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have say 3 spans as below :

```
<span  class = "testVar1" onClick = "testFunction(Var1)">
<span  class = "testVar2" onClick = "testFunction(Var2)">
<span  class = "testVar3" onClick = "testFunction(Var3)">
testFunction(var){
    here I assign class "on" to the span which calls this function
}
```

If span with class testVar1 calls this then it becomes

```
<span  class = "testVar1 on" onClick = "testFunction(Var1)"></span>
```

My Css is as below

```
.test .on {
    some CSS
}
```

Is there a way in CSS where I can use a variable and apply css to those span which is clicked?
Like

```
.test[Var1 or Var2 or Var3] .on {
    some CSS
}
```

I have achieved it by using multiple selectors manually like#

```
.testVar1 .on {
    some CSS
}
.testVar2 .on {
    some CSS
}
```

I have read the post [Using regular expression in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903313/using-regular-expression-in-css) , it,s helpful but not answering my question.

In this post css is applied to all the element, but I want css to be applied only to the element which called the function.
and so on.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: `.testVar1.on {    sumCSS}` ???

Comment: Edited the question!

Comment: Instead of `testFunction(Var1)` you can simply do `testFunction(this)`. On each of your spans. No matter if 3 or 100000.

Comment: a *perfect* duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/8903313/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things too complicated. Just use the same CSS class on all of them, then add the click listener programmatically, not as an inline `onlick` listener:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('span.test').forEach(
  span =>
  span.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log(`you clicked ${span.innerText}`) 
      span.classList.toggle('on')
  })
)
```

```css
.test {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px;
}

.test.on {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">foo</span>
<span class="test">bar</span>
<span class="test">baz</span>
```

If you insist on inline event listeners (you really shouldn't, it's widely considered bad practice), for this simple example it's probably even easier:

```js
function foobar(span) {
  console.log(`you clicked ${span.innerText}`)
  span.classList.toggle('on')
}
```

```css
.test {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px;
}

.test.on {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="test" onclick="foobar(this)">foo</span>
<span class="test" onclick="foobar(this)">bar</span>
<span class="test" onclick="foobar(this)">baz</span>
```

Comment: It worked! Infact I was going with a complicated logic. There is no need to use multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex selector: `span[class^='test']` which means select every span with class start with "test".
You can combine it with another class (`.on`) like that: `span[class^='test'].on`

As for inline code, you can do something like that:

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span[class^="test"]'); // select all spans
for (var i=0; i < spans.length; i++) { // iterate them
  spans[i].addEventListener('click',function() { // add event listener to them
this.classList.add('on'); // set class on click
  });
}
```

```css
span[class^='test'] {color: blue;}
span[class^='test'].on { color: red;  }
```

```html
<span class="testVar1">1</span>
<span class="testVar2">2</span>
<span class="testVar3">3</span>
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772290/css-selector-that-applies-to-elements-with-two-classes) for selecting element with more then one class.
And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903313/using-regular-expression-in-css) for regExp selector.
Enjoy code!