# Cypress find element with id contains and have span

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I am new to Cypress and I want to find the element whose id is dynamic but id have some specific text. example.

```
...
<div class="col2">
 <button id="random-city-name_type-125" class="btn-secondary">
  <span>
   <i class="icon">::before</i>
   "some city"
  <span>
 <button>
</div>
<div class="col3">
 <button id="random-account-number_type-119" class="btn-secondary">
  <span>
   <i class="icon">::before</i>
   "abc text"
  <span>
 <button>
</div>
...
```

Here, I want to find the button whose id contains **account-number** and have text inside span "abc text" and want to **click on that button** which open popup.

I tried following.

```
cy.visit("localhost:5000");
cy.wait(4000)
cy.get('[id^=account-number-]').find('span').contains("abc text").click(); //This gives me error.
```

But, it gives error that element not found. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from using `^` with your CSS selector. The `^` symbol means that the [matching element *must begin with the selector given.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49782582/11625850) Instead, you can use `*` which will check if the selector contains (not limiting to beginning or ending with.)

```js
cy.get('[id*="account-number"]')
  .find('span')
  .contains('abc text')
  .click();
```

Additionally, you'll only need the `.find()` between the `.get()` and the `.contains()` if you specifically need to have the `span` found. Using `cy.get(...).contains(...)` uses the yielded `.get()` element as the parent that Cypress uses for `.contains()`. (Alternatively, you could also include the `span` in the `.get()` selector

```js
cy.get('[id*="account-number"]') // or .get('[id*="account-number"] span')
  .contains('abc text')
  .click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath

```
cy.xpath("//div[@class='col3']//button//span//i").click()
```

Comment: How can I find `account-number` from id using Xpath?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `within` to scope your next commands inside your id section.

```js
cy.get('[id*="random-account-number"]').within(() => {
  cy.get('span').should('include.text', 'abc text')
})
```