# How to select classes in bulk with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a table with classes such as "column-1", "column-2" and so on...

I want to select all the classes that have the word "column" with "-" after it and "some number", as you can see from the structure of the classes I mentioned above.

I want to do it with CSS.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903313/using-regular-expression-in-css

Answer (score -1):

## UPDATED ANSWER

```
div[class^="column-"] {
 /* this selector selects every element start with "column-" */ 
}
```

---

## OLD ANSWER

these 2 classes to every column

- every column should have the className `column`
- additionally, add className `column-n` [n=1,2,3...] to each respective column

now you can select every column with,

```
.column {
 ........
}
```

select an individual column with `n=1,2,3...`

```
.column-n{
 .....
}
```

- List item

Comment: This is not near the user asked for. Please don't post answer without reading the question.

Comment: I've changed it take a look

Comment: Do you even know what user is asking? Your edit makes more confusion then before.